# Selecting using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 and geom_bar to summarize the number of spices in a column.  I want the number of bars to be restricted to a value, say count >  10.
My code is:

```
ggplot(r_df, aes(spice, colour="black", fill = "orange")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  stat_count(geom = "text", colour = "black", size = 3.,
             aes(label = after_stat(count)), position=position_stack(vjust=1.05)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=.6))
```

Since the code is counting the number of each item for me, I don't think I can subset prior to executing the plot.  I am hoping there is a simple way to put the count>10 into the ggplot function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have the exact data in `r_df`, I'm taking a guess here. You should be able to use `filter()` prior to building your plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

r_df %>%
  group_by(spice) %>%
  filter(n() > 10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(spice, colour = "black", fill = "orange")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  stat_count(
    geom = "text", 
    colour = "black", 
    size = 3.,
    aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
    position = position_stack(vjust = 1.05)
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .6))
```